# Entity Framework: Help Creating Database using Code first Approach

Tags: c#, database, entity

OK 2 questions:
1. I am new to Databases and I want to learn the code first approach to creating a Database. I have used the Model-first approach a few times. Can anyone help me with coding this DB using Code-first approach (I also would like to add an Employee table if possible)?
Here is the link to the DB Diagram:

http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/customers_and_orders/images/customers_and_orders_ref_data_model.gif

2. Also, how would I insert into lets say the customer table / customer address  address all in one go, using entity framework of course?

Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like follows:

Please note the this solution has done as a console application.

Please add the following class to do this as code first:

```
        public class Customer
            {
                [Key]
                public int CustomerId { get; set; }
                public string FirstName { get; set; }
                public string MiddleName { get; set; }
                public string LastName { get; set; }
                public string Phone { get; set; }
                public string Email { get; set; }
                public string CustomerOtherDetails { get; set; }
            }

            public class CustomerAddress
            {
                [ForeignKey("Customer")]
                public int CustomerId { get; set; }
                [ForeignKey("AddressType")]
                public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
                [ForeignKey("Address")]
                public int AddressId { get; set; }
                [Key]
                public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
                public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
                public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
                public virtual AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
                public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
            }

            public class AddressType
            {
                [Key]
                public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
                public string AddressTypeDescriptiom { get; set; }
            }

            public class Address
            {
                [Key]
                public int AddressId { get; set; }
                public string Line1 { get; set; }
                public string Line2 { get; set; }
                public string Line3 { get; set; }
                public string City { get; set; }

            }
```

When you do it Code First approach you need to create the model out of the class you created and it can be done as follows:

Context class should be like follows:

```
    public class CustomerContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomerContext()
            : base("DBConnectionString")
        {
            //If model change, It will re-create new database.
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CustomerContext>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Set primary key to Customer table
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(m => m.CustomerId);


            //set primary key to Address table
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddress>().HasKey(m => m.DateFrom);

            modelBuilder.Entity<AddressType>().HasKey(m => m.AddressTypeId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasKey(m => m.AddressId);

            //Set foreign key property
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddress>().HasRequired(t => t.Customer)
                .WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.CustomerId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddress>().HasRequired(t => t.AddressType)
                .WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.AddressTypeId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddress>()
                .HasRequired(t => t.Address)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.AddressId);
        }
```

Database creating and the inserting address with a customer should be like below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                using (var ctx = new CustomerContext())
                {
                    //ctx.Database.Create(); // This command can be used to create the database using the code first class
                    ctx.CustomerAddresses.Add(new CustomerAddress
                    {
                        AddressType = new AddressType
                        {
                            AddressTypeId = 1,
                            AddressTypeDescriptiom = "Test"
                        },
                        Customer = new Customer
                        {
                            CustomerId = 1,
                            FirstName = "Customer 1"
                        },
                        Address = new Address
                        {
                            Line1 = "Line 1",
                            City = "USA"
                        },
                        DateFrom = DateTime.Now,
                        DateTo = DateTime.Now
                    });

                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Connection string should like below:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DBConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=CustomerDB;Integrated Security=true"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

Please note following note the above code need following references.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
```

I tried this and it works as you expected. Please let me know whether you need a sample project on this.

Hope this helps you.

**EDITED:**

To configure self reference in code first please do as below:

```
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public int? ParentProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual Product ParentProduct { get; set; }
    }
```

Add the following code lines in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasKey(m => m.ProductId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().
                HasOptional(e => e.ParentProduct).
                WithMany().
                HasForeignKey(m => m.ParentProductId);
```

Comment: Firstly thank you very much Oshadha for your response. This partly answers my questions, however there are a few things further to your response that I need to know such as the circular relationships on the products table -> how would I implement this in code first??

Comment: Let me know the things that I haven't answered in above answer.

Comment: Oshadha thank you once again your help is much appreciated, now I just need to know where to place this code. Will it lie in the models folder, in one of my classes? where would you put it ? (I'm using MVC5 asp.net application) and is there a way to add this DB to the existing ASPIdent DBContext that comes out of the box in a new MVC5 project? therefore kind of extending it?

Comment: You can keep your code first code in a separate project called `Company.Project.Model` and I'm not getting the second part of your question. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: OK.. when you start a new project is VS201* you get the option to use MVC and so forth. Then once the project is created automatically with an application db context called applicationDBContext. DO you know how I would extend this premade context model and insert the DB above?

Comment: Just replace the ApplicationDBConnect(auto created code) code with what we created. By the way if you feel like above answer helped you. Please make it as answered so then others can benefit from what we did here. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. For the Employee Table, You Can create a class (Employee.cs):

   public class Employees
   {

   public string FName {get;set;}
   public string LName {get;set;}
   public string Position {get;set;}
   public string Email {get;set;}
   [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
   public string FullName
   {
       get
       {
           return LName + ", " + FName;
       }
   }

}

2. For the insert, You can do :

   ```
    var users = new List<User>
       {
           new User{FName ="Chris", LName ="Fajardo",Position=@"Dev",Email="test.test@test.ae"}
       };
       users.ForEach(s => context.User.Add(s));
       context.SaveChanges();
   ```